How signal generation affect its spectrum
Im trying to get dft of hanning window. Im trying different methods of generating the same signal, yet im resulting with such different graph of signal spectrum.
def dft(signal):
    dft_out = [complex(0,0)] * len(signal)
    for k in range(0, len(signal)):
        for n in range(len(signal)):
            dft_out[k] += signal[n] * np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*k*n / len(signal))
    return dft_out

def hanning_window(wnd_len): # cpy paste from numpy implementation
    n = np.arange(1-wnd_len, wnd_len, 2)
    return 0.5 + 0.5*np.cos(np.pi*n/(wnd_len-1))

def hanning_window2(wnd_len):
    n = np.arange(1-wnd_len, wnd_len, 1)
    return 0.5*(1.0 - np.cos((2*np.pi*n)/wnd_len))

def hanning_window3(wnd_len):
    arr = [1.0] * wnd_len
    return [elem * (0.5*(1.0 - np.cos((2*np.pi*n)/wnd_len))) for n, elem in enumerate(arr)]

wnd_len = 100
hann1 = hanning_window(wnd_len)
hann2 = hanning_window2(wnd_len)
hann3 = hanning_window3(wnd_len)
hann4 = np.hanning(wnd_len)
xf = list(range(0, wnd_len))

hann1_sp = 20* np.log10(np.abs(dft(hann1)))
hann2_sp = 20* np.log10(np.abs(dft(hann2)))
hann3_sp = 20* np.log10(np.abs(dft(hann3)))
hann4_sp = 20* np.log10(np.abs(dft(hann4)))


Im unable to explain why I get so much different result, shape of hann windows is exactly the same, yet resulting spectrum is so much different.
I feel it may be issue corresponding to floating poind round-off error, but im not 100% sure about it. Im especially curious about third case, where hann window is generated though simple array multiplication not arange spaced values

Have you considered to compare these signals directly in time domain? Like take your hann1 as a reference and eval the deviation to all others?

@Irreducible hann1 - hann3 gives me deltas varying from e-02 to e-05. I would like consider it as a satysfying error, but again it may correspond to later floating point error when we process signal with dft function.

there must be something wrong, when I read your hanning_window3, then since arr is a list full of value 1.0, all elem are always 1.0, and so, the result must be identical to your hanning_window2, but it's clearly not. Could you fix the indentation of your python code such that we can actually copy and paste it and be sure to run 100% the same code as you?

also, eliminate one source of error and use numpy's fft instead of your self-written DFT

@Marcus indentation is fixed. What about hann2 and hann3. Hann2 is twice len of hann3, and plot is only for half of it length. That maybe expalantion. About using self made dft, it does not explain different results.

and your windows have different length; for example, hanning_window2(100) should have length 199, whereas hanning_window3(100) should have length 100; you can't directly compare these two.

@user8464651 if the code you wrote was correct, we wouldn't need to look into differences in results, so how can you be sure that your DFT is not to blame? (It's not that I disagree, but your problem here calls for careful elimination of sources of errors. So, let's stick to things you know work, please). But honestly, we don't need to debug any further. You have two things that are the same code (hanning_window(100) and np.hanning(100)), these seem to give the same result. You have one implementation that gives an incorrect length (hanning_window2), so to compare that you need to fix

it first, so the only thing that's left to compare is np.hanning(100) to hanning_window3(100), and these, by looking at the calculations alone, have different phase, and differ by pretty large amounts in values, so one must be wrong.

by different phase are you mean that it is unfiltered? I remember that i had similar problem when i tried to get phase spectrum by atan2. Filtering all values < e-05 filter also makes spectrum less noisy.

no, by different phase I mean the phase of the cosine, it's different.

The primary issue is not having enough interpolated samples in the DFT to properly estimate the desired Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) as a continuous function in the frequency domain. The simple solution is to zero-pad the samples prior to taking the FFT which will result in more interpolated samples of the DTFT. The DTFT of the 100 sample Hanning Window would appear as plotted below with the frequency axis extending from $0$ to $f_s$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate, consistent with the FFT samples as typically ordered:

Note how it has 99 zeros. The DFT will provide us samples on this DTFT, so depending on the exact location of those samples, we could end up with all zeros or other values according to the off-zero sample locations, which is what the OP is seeing. I replicated the OP's plots using the scipy.fft function and had the following result:

I repeated this by zero padding out to $2^{16}$ samples as scipy.fft.fft(hann1, 2**16) which zero pads the output resulting in more interpolated samples on the underlying DTFT plotted above, and get the following result (and note how the OP's hanning_window2 function is providing two cycles of the hanning window):

